# HCMGIS Stamen Toner layer disappears when I zoom in too much

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, wms, stamen

I am trying to use the Stamen Toner layer in QGIS as a background to my map layout. This layer is made available via the HCMGIS plugin.

When I load this into my QGIS session as a layer it seems to load fine. However, when I zoom in beyond a certain level the layer disappears.

How can I prevent that the layer disappear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the XYZ tile version of the Stamen Toner base map. URL available [here](https://stamen-tiles.a.ssl.fastly.net/toner/%7Bz%7D/%7Bx%7D/%7By%7D.png)

```
https://stamen-tiles.a.ssl.fastly.net/toner/{z}/{x}/{y}.png
```

In the Browser panel, right-click `XYZ Tiles` and choose `New Connection`. Enter a name and paste the URL.

You can zoom in as far as you like but the resolution suffers <1:1000

[image]